# Как получить значения после определенного элемента?

Tags: python

Есть список -

```
a = ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8','test9','test10']
```

И переменная -

```
b = test4
```

Как получить значения которые идут после переменной b из списка a.

Результат должен быть таким

['test5','test6','test7','test8','test9','test10']

Answer (score 4):

Вот так вот:

```
a = ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7','test8','test9','test10']
b = 'test4'

print(a[a.index(b) + 1:])
```